# How to prove if $P(A|B)>P(A)$ then $P(B|A)>P(B)$

Tags: probability

How to prove that If $P(A|B)>P(A)$ then $P(B|A)>P(B)$

Comment: Do you know the definition of conditional probability: $P(A\,|\,B)={P(A \cap B)\over P(B)}$?

Comment: @DavidMitra Shouldn't that be $P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: @AndrewD Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

$$P(A|B)>P(A)$$

$$\frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(B)}>P(A)$$
$$\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}>P(A)$$
Now, since $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are positive.
$$\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(A)}>P(B)$$
$$P(B|A)>P(B)$$
$$\square$$
It should be noted this works with all other comparison operators as well.

Comment: Does the third step use Bayes' rule?

Comment: It used the definition of conditional probability. $P(B|A)=P(A \land B)÷P(A)$