# If $P(A\mid B) > P(A)$ then $P(B\mid A) > P(B)$

Tags: probability

You guys have no idea how I prove it? I already tried several ways, but had no success.

If $P(A\mid B)>P(A)$ then $P(B\mid A)>P(B)$.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying $P(A\mid B) > P(A)$ on both sides by $P(B)/P(A)$?

Comment: Can you describe some of the ways you tried? I suggest you start by writing out $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(B\mid A)$ using their definitions.

Comment: I tried stipulating values ​​and using the definition

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean about stipulating values, but why don't you start by rewriting the statement in terms of the definition, getting rid of all the conditional probabilities?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441228/how-to-prove-if-pabpa-then-pbapb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
P(A) < P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$
$$
P(A) < \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$
Multiply both sides by $P(B)$ (this works if $P(B)>0$):
$$
P(A)P(B) < P(A\text{ $\cap$ }B).
$$
Now divide both sides by $P(A)$ (this works if $P(A)>0$):
$$
P(B)<\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}.
$$
This says
$$
P(B) < P(B\mid A).
$$

Comment: Could the person who down-voted this answer explain their objections?

Comment: As you must know by now, @Michael Hardly, I hardly downvote here and I did not downvoted you. Yet I'd like to know where did you get $\,P(A)<P(A\mid B)\;$ from...? I'd rather say the inequality is the other way around.

Comment: Someone decided to change $A\text{ and }B$ to $A\cap B$, but it was done not by coding it as A\cap B, but rather as A\text{ \$\cap\$ }B.  One of the dumber uses of TeX code I've seen in a while.

Comment: @DonAntonio : The inequality given in the question was $P(A\mid B)>P(A)$.  That's the same as $P(A)<P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: Oh, I see @Michael: you began your proof by assuming the given condition...fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio : If I hadn't been assuming the condition that was given, then WHY would you say the inequality was the other way around?

Comment: my idea is that the probability of an event is greater than or equal the probability of that same event **conditioned** to this or that...am I wrong? I'm not that fond of probability nor much of applied mathematics, so don't be surprised if I'm saying nonsense.

Comment: Certainly that is wrong.  In some cases the inequality goes one way and in some cases it goes the other way.

Comment: Could you add some example contradicting my claim, @Michael?

Comment: @DonAntonio : The simplest example is where $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive and each has positive probability.  Then $P(A\mid B)=0$ and $P(A)>0$.  A slightly more involved example is a probability space with $1000$ equally probable outcomes, and $A$ contains $500$ of those outcomes and $B$ contains $200$ and $A\cap B$ contains just one.  Then $P(A\mid B)=1/200$, and $P(A)=1/2$.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, @Michael: if $\;P(A)>0\;$  and$\,P(A\mid B)=0\;$ then certainly $\,P(A)\rlap{\;\;/}<P(A\mid B)\;$ !

Comment: Oh, you want the inequality to go the other way: Extreme case: $A=B=$ a subset of size $500$ of the space of $1000$ equally probable outcomes.  Then $P(A)=1/2$ and $P(A\mid B)=1$.  Slightly less extreme case: $|A|=500=|B|$ and $A$ has just one member that's not a member of $B$, and $B$ has just one member that's not a member of $A$.  Then $P(A)=1/2$ and $P(A\mid B)=499/500$.

Comment: In a space of $1000$ equally probable outcomes suppose $A$, $B$ are subsets each of size $200$.  Then $|A\cap B|$ may have any size $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,200\}$.  Then $P(A)=200/1000$ and $P(A\mid B)=k/200$.  So $P(A\mid B)$ may have any value in a range going from $0$ to $200$ by increments of $1/200$.

Comment: Ah, the example of the $\,A=B=$ subset of 500...etc. cleared that up completely. Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted because I judged that a full answer to this question was worse than a thoughtful hint.

Comment: @dfeuer : I give hints when I see evidence that the poster will understand them.  Here there wasn't enough information for me to be confident of that.

Comment: I think a definition of $P(A\mid B)$ should be sufficient. If it is not, I think the asker would be better served by one-on-one discussion with a teacher. It's probably a philosophical disagreement. I have sometimes asked questions, seen that the answers are beyond my ability to understand, and simply dropped the matter—hopefully some day I will learn enough to comprehend such.

Comment: @dfeuer : Discussion with _someone_ would probably have helped.  That that _should_ be sufficient seems irrelevant when the student says he's tried a number of things without success.  Apparently it wasn't sufficient for him.  If he'd told us specifically why he'd done, then maybe that would have started the discussion that led to his figuring it out.

Comment: I agree that including more information in the question would have been helpful, but I personally prefer to err on the side of caution--better to let the student *fail* to answer the question, thereby getting the teacher's attention, than to give them an answer and let them slide through the class understanding less and less over time. Obviously a *lazy* student can only improve with a peculiarly inspiring teacher, but one who is *ashamed* to ask for help is probably best served by being pushed to get it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $\Pr(A\cap B)$ in two different ways using conditional probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

By Bayes theorem:

$$P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)\iff \frac{P(A\mid B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B\mid A)}{P(B)}$$

So, if the left side is greater than one so is the right side...