# Proof with conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

> If $P(A) >0$, $P(B) > 0$, and $P(A) < P(A|B)$, show that $P(B) < P(B|A)$.

$P(A|B) \cdot P(B) = P(B|A) \cdot P(A)$. So I thought that since $P(A|B)>P(A)$ is given, we have to have $P(B|A) > P(B)$ in order to ensure the equality. But I'm not too sure about this. Is there a better proof?

Comment: See this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453522/if-pa-mid-b-pa-then-pb-mid-a-pb

Searched from: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24P(A)%20%3C%20P(A%7CB)%24%2C%20%24P(B)%20%3C%20P(B%7CA)%24&p=1

Comment: Well... $$\frac{P(A\mid B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}=\frac{P(B\mid A)}{P(B)}$$ hence the LHS is $>1$ if and only if the RHS is $>1$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, $$P(A/B)> P(A)$$

$$ \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P (B)} > P(A)$$

$$P(A \cap B) > P(A) \cdot P(B)$$

So, $$P(B/A)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P (A)}  > \frac{P(A) \cdot P(B)}{P(A)} > P(B)$$

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler to use $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ and note that the stated inequality $P(A)<P(A|B)$ becomes
$$ P(A)P(B) < P(A\cap B)$$ 
which is symmetric in $A$ and $B$. So it is equivalent 
to $P(B)<P(A\cap B)/P(A)=P(B|A)$

Comment: "the stated inequality becomes symmetric in $A$ and $B$". I don't really understand this sentence, could you further elaborate?